# Encryption/decryption problems with Expo's SecureStorage and redux-saga

Tags: react-native, expo, redux-saga

I am making a React Native app with a login-module with token support, so the user doesn't have to login every time.

The thing is that I sometimes get the error:

```
Error: Could not encrypt/decrypt the item in SecureStore
    at createErrorFromErrorData (NativeModules.js:146)
    at NativeModules.js:95
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (MessageQueue.js:397)
    at MessageQueue.js:127
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:297)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:126)
```

The error just occurs at random, so I have no idea how to find out what is wrong and I do not know how to debug the problem.

All I do is checking whether a token already is stored:

```
let userToken = yield call(SecureStore.getItemAsync, "userToken");
```

And saving a token received from the server if there isn't one already:

```
yield call(SecureStore.setItemAsync, "userToken", token);
```

I haven't managed to find other issues regarding this except a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/814) more than a year old with no proper solution.

Has anyone experienced the same problem and found out what causes it?

**Update:**
I have no problems working on the mobile, but it would be nice to be able to use SecureStore on the emulator.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not and I haven't had access to the project for almost two years, so I should probably delete the question.

Comment: Got this one today in a few hundred Android devices. Maybe one day we'll learn what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing all data in SecureStore you set before. It worked for me.

I faced the same problem after uninstalling and reinstalling Expo GO. To address the problem, I cleared all data in SecureStore and reassigned them. It worked :)